# how to query sum for one field of two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two mysql table.
Table: bill

```
id | billtype | amount | advid |   paydate  |adjid |  adjdate   |
 1 | electric | 10000  |  123  | 2017-01-01 | 50   | 2017-01-03 |
 2 |   Water  |  5000  |  124  | 2017-02-01 |  0   | 0000-00-00 |
 3 |   Shirt  |   500  |  125  | 2017-03-01 |  0   | 0000-00-00 |
```

Table: advance

```
 id | advid | amount | balance | purpose |
 1  | 123   | 50000  |  20000  |   Bill  |
 2  | 124   | 70000  |  10000  |   Bill  |
 3  | 125   | 55000  |  15000  | Uniform |
 4  | 124   | 60000  |  10000  |   Bill  |
```

I want to create a drop down menu so that to select those 'advance' which are not adjusted yet (adjid=0 and adjdate=0000-00-00) in Table: bill and that drop down menu will also contain the total value of advance for same advance id (advid) like below:

```
<option>Bill-130000</option>
<option>Uniform-55000</option>
```

As total 130000 (70000+60000) advance is taken against advance id `124`, so the Total amount of Advance in Option menu should be 130000 in case of Bill. But I am failed to calculate total amount of advance accurately:

```
SELECT sum(a.amount), purpose FROM bill as b, advance as a WHERE b.paydate!='0000-00-00' AND b.adjid!=0 AND a.advid=b.advid GROUP BY a.advid
```

Total amount in `<option></option>` is not coming actual.

What would be the right query for this purpose?

Comment: The results you got are correct. The condition `b.paydate!='0000-00-00' AND b.adjid!=0` will give only `advid`= 123 from `bill` table, therefore will give you only 50000.

Comment: Typically, you'd GROUP by the non-aggregated columns in your SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT SUM(a.amount) AS amount, 
       MAX(purpose)  AS purpose 
FROM   advance a 
WHERE  a.advid IN (
               SELECT b.advid 
               FROM   bill b 
               WHERE  b.paydate = '0000-00-00' 
                      AND b.adjid = 0) 
GROUP  BY a.advid
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your Code.